# How can I ssh, in google cloud, and make a backup of my site directly to my hard drive instead of on my server? Don't have enough space on my server

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

How can I ssh in google cloud console and make a backup of my site directly to my hard drive as opposed to on my server? I don't have space on my server and want the back up file on my hard drive instead so I don't run out of space.

Comment: `scp - r user@remote_address:/path/to/directory /path/to/local/folder` can be used. On a different note why not use filezilla and backup.

Comment: In additional to Paandittya's good comment, consider backing up to Google Cloud Storage first and then download from Google Cloud Storage to your desktop. You could setup a cron job (or install third party software) to automatically backup your server to Cloud Storage.

Comment: @Paandittya I can't use filezilla bc there are file permission issues with a lot of files and folders

Comment: Alright. In such a case you should look into `rsync`. It syncs files and/or folders along with permissions, ownership, symlinks etc. `man rsync` for more info.